# Account linking on google actions

Tags: actions-on-google

We are using basic instructions for account linking with a skill realized with google actions, dialogflow and external fullfillment.

We use **systemIntent** `actions.intent.SIGN_IN` to start the account linking process, which allows us to get user's email.

However, the default text used by google to require permission is very difficult to understand for users. It seems that the user is opening a new account, while he is only giving permission to pass the email to the skill.
Is there the possibility to **modify** such text?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. The text is specifically chosen by Google to be standard, consistent across Actions, and make it clear what permissions the user is granting to your Action.

Comment: Thank you. That's a pity, because actually the simple act to require permission to use the email leads to a long response by Google which is difficult to be understood by the user. There is a strong risk that the user leaves the action because he thinks that some new account will be created.